# Assigning many double quotes to string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with many double quotes like so:

```
  string x = " I "" Am" bla"" bla" ble"  ";
```

I know that I can escape each individual double quote and that it will not return an error but:

- I am copying very large strings with different text each time;
- I cannot afford to individually escape thousands of characters;
- Using the character @ before the first double quote does not work.

Is there any other way to automate the process apart from downloading the strings to a text file on the computer and importing it with File.ReadAllText?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can write some code to escape them for you, and run that on your clipboard.

Comment: But you generally shouldn't embed data like that in source.

Comment: Have you tried using the replace function in your IDE to replace `"` with `\"`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. If the strings are data then the double quotes don't matter, it's just a string. The only time you need to escape the double quotes is if they are hard-coded in your source.

Comment: How are you reading in those strings? Isn't the source already giving you escaped strings?

Comment: That's what happens when you hard-code data. Use a configuration file(s) instead

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); you've got “very large strings” and thought you'd “escape each individual double quote”, but that “does not work”. You should probably instead be storing your “very large strings” as embedded files or resources. Show us example strings and what you're trying to use them for.

Comment: That's the right approach; if you have lots of large strings, **put them in a resource**.  That way you can update them without having to change the source code, you can localize them, and so on.

Comment: I need to copy a string from clipboard that contains more than 50 double quotes and hard code it. But don't know an easy way to escape every double quote. Such as HTML snippets

Comment: @SLaks I used your solution and wrote something to escape every double quote apart from the outer ones. I thought there would be way to just automatically ignore every single double quote apart from the outer most ones, but apparently there isn't one.

Comment: Good idea; you're a computer programmer; if you have a problem, **write a computer program to solve it**! That's what we do.

Comment: SmartPaster may be a solution for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=martinw.SmartPaster2013

Comment: @AwesomeSauce: Even if your goal is to copy a string from clipboard and hard-code it, the answer is still to put the string in a resource.  If it's a quick and dirty one-off program, then save the string to disk and use `File.ReadAllText`.

Answer (score 0):

if you asking how to write characters like : "

`string x = " I \"\" Am\" bla\"\" bla\" ble\" ";`

and we use @ before the first double quote to return new line like this

```
string x = @" bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla";
```